# ClassCastException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection cannot be cast to org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss7.x, classcastexception

I want to get `PGConnection` from PosgreSQL connection in JBOSS AS7 (Data source postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar)

I've got cast exception when used `(WrappedConnection)connection`.
So now I use reflection (JDK 1.7):

```
private static PGConnection getPGConnction(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    if(connection instanceof PGConnection) {
        return (PGConnection)connection;
    }
    try {
        Class[] parms = null;
        Method method =(connection.getClass()).getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection", parms);
        return (PGConnection) jdbc4Conn;
    } catch ...
```

and catch exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection cannot be cast to org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection
```

It is the same class!!!  How can it be?

Comment: Looks like a classloader issue. Check where are you keeping the JDBC jar files for Postgres

Comment: Why are you writing code to get connections when you should be using JBOSS JNDI pooled connections?

Comment: Is this in a webapp? A common issue is having the library in the web server classpath and the webapp classpath.

Comment: To duffymo: I've got connection using JNDI. Problem is I can not get PGConnection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a class can not be cast to itself, if means you have 2 copies loaded by different classloaders. In a webapp, this can easily happen if you have the JDBC driver jar both in the application itself and in the app server's lib. Or, in case of .ear packaging, in both `war/WEB-INF/lib` and `ear/lib`. Make sure there is only a single jar on the classpath and you will get rid of the error. You can pass `-verbose:class` when starting Java to get more information on where the classes are being loaded from. Btw, what is the point of reflection in your code? Can't you just call `getUnderlyingConnection` normally?

Comment: I think you are right about two driver entities. I'll certainly check it. Thank you very much. I used reflection because direct call (WrapConnection)conn.getUnderlyingConnection() ended with ClassCastException. Guess through the same reason - two driver entities.

Answer (score 1):

Per [kaqqao's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25474184/294657), I

1. Deleted postgres as project library (changed scope from compile to provided)
2. Added jboss-deployment-structure.xml (with module name="deployment.postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar" dependency) to project web-inf.

   So problem is solved